# MySQL - products list table and group prices

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables:

- products table: id, name, price
- prices table:   id, product_id, group_id, price

Query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.price, pr.price AS newPrice, pr.id AS prID
FROM products p
  LEFT JOIN prices pr ON pr.product_id = p.id
WHERE pr.group_id = '1'
ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

I need see all products and if filled prices than get result from prices table.
But I see only filled datas, when I'm writing "WHERE"

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `LEFT JOIN`The filter on the `prices` table should be placed at the `ON` clause

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.price, pr.price AS newPrice, pr.id AS prID
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN prices pr ON pr.product_id = p.id AND pr.group_id = 1
ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

Comment: its need 8 minute, I'm waiting it. Thank you again!

Comment: *"When using LEFT JOINThe filter on the prices table should be placed at the ON clause"* @GiorgiBulia to be more clear. Unless the filter condition was `pr.group_id IS NULL`  then it was in the correct location.. The `"NOT IS NULL"` filters on the `LEFT JOIN` should be in the `ON` cluase